# Relative imports in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Some authoritative names have commented and/or answered about the general problem of `relative imports` when trying to run a script within the module directory here: [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

My issue is that the `Pycharm` IDE *is* parsing the module and running it in this same directory. So I end up with import errors. Note that there is an `__init__.py` in the package.   Looks fine to `pycharm` parser

[image]

```
from . logger import *   # Logger is a module in same package
```

*But* ..

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/git/bluej/fusion/python/pointr/bluej/util/DB.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . logger import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

the `Run Configuration` was created by right-clicking in the module.  The auto generated version is like this: having the `working directory` the same as the script dir.  `/git/bluej/fusion/python/pointr/bluej/util` (note the package is `pointr.blue.util`):

[image]

I tried out putting the `Working Directory` at the base `python` directory level:  `/git/bluej/fusion/python/`

[image]

However that did not have any effect.

Responding to a comment: `logger` is not the root package and so the following code does not work:

[image]

How can I develop, debug, and run modules with relative imports in `Pycharm` ?

Comment: in terminal you need to see from which directory location you are executing the code, is that code depends on other packages, in pycharm it is assumed the directory is the base of the project and all code is executed from that directory level not from the package/module level like that u r tring to do in terminal, if you execute it from directory level it may work

Comment: @sahasrara62  I am running from within `Pycharm` not the terminal

Comment: `from . logger import *` here is space typo error ? if yes then do `from .logger import *`, also this may [help](https://napuzba.com/a/import-error-relative-no-parent)

Comment: @sahasrara62  I tried with and without the `space` before the `.`: no difference in behavior.  Also i had already seen that other reference: it is not as authoritative or complete as the SOF question I linked above.  Also none of them talks about the specfics of running inside `pycharm`

Comment: i just tried created this sample project code, if you just do `from logger import *` and run the way you are executing this script, it will work fine (don't know why `.` is not taking work here ideally)

Comment: `from logger import *` does not work because `logger` is not the base level package: see my updated question.

Comment: if in your project relative import done using `.` then remove those

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209967/discussion-between-javadba-and-sahasrara62).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

- Change script name to module name : see the first selection under `Configuration`
- Change working directory to root of the hierarchy
- hope for the best